# Karate UI tests are Failing in Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, karate, gui-testing, karate-call-single

There are 2 issues:

1. Default Chrome Browser is NOT working in LOCAL for karate UI tests (Safari is working fine)
2. Karate UI tests are failing with the below errors:

   SEVERE: command error: [/usr/bin/google-chrome, --remote-debugging-port=9222, --no-first-run, --user-data-dir=/home/jenkins/agent/workspace/_myproject_PR-001/app/target/chrome_1672115894098, --disable-popup-blocking] - Cannot run program "/usr/bin/google-chrome" (in directory "target/chrome_1672115894098"): error=2, No such file or directory

   org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:9222 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused), options: {type=chrome, target=null}

Please let me know if you know any resolution on the above issue

Comment: 1) maybe chrome is not installed, refer docs: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/tree/master/karate-core#configure-driver 2) you will have to figure this out on your own as this can be related to your specific environment. you can search other answers: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bkarate%5D+chrome+connection+refused